# why object.keys() to Object literal and Object.create() has different result?

Tags: javascript

[mdn Object.keys()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) defines it will return an array of a given object's own enumerable properties.

```
var USComicPublishers = {
countryOfOrigin : {
    value  : "USA",
    enumerable: false,
    writable: false,
    configurable: false
},
medium : {
    value  : "comic books",
    enumerable: true,
    writable: false,
    configurable: false
}
}
```

as the Object.keys() define, it should return `['medium']`

but it return `['countryOfOrigin', 'medium']`

then I use `Object.create()` to wrap it, it will return `['medium']`

```
var us2 = Object.create({}, USComicPublishers)
console.log(us2)
// return ['medium']
```

does `Object literal` has different behavior in `Object.create()`?

```js
var USComicPublishers = {
    countryOfOrigin : {
        value  : "USA",
        enumerable: false,
        writable: false,
        configurable: false
    },
    medium : {
        value  : "comic books",
        enumerable: true,
        writable: false,
        configurable: false
    }
}
console.log(Object.keys(USComicPublishers))
var us2 = Object.create({}, USComicPublishers)
console.log(Object.keys(us2))
console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyNames(us2))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there is a difference. When creating an object literal, it's not possible to set the `enumerable`, `writable` and `configurable` properties like that. Instead, you're setting properties with all those values set to `true` and `value` set to the value you're giving (you'll notice in your first example that `USComicPublishers.medium` will be an object and `USComicPublishers.medium.value === "comic books"`)

You would have to create the object literal and then apply the properties using [`Object.defineProperties`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperties) if you wanted the same results.

```js
var USComicPublishersData = {
    countryOfOrigin : {
        value  : "USA",
        enumerable: false,
        writable: false,
        configurable: false
    },
    medium : {
        value  : "comic books",
        enumerable: true,
        writable: false,
        configurable: false
    }
}
var USComicPublishers = {};
Object.defineProperties(USComicPublishers, USComicPublishersData);
console.log(Object.keys(USComicPublishers))
```

Answer (score 3):

Given an object literal — `{ foo: bar }` — `bar` is the **value** the property holds. It is the plain and simple value. It doesn't determine anything *about* the properly (such as if it is enumerable).

When passed to `Object.create`, the value is taken as a **description of the property**. This determines if the property is enumerable etc.